How do I set the background for the .Net Maui status bar?

Can you please tell me how I can set the background image and background colors so that they extend to the status bar (the way it looks on the design)? I don't need this for the whole application, but for a specific page. Is this possible? Thank you in advance for the answer

This question is similar to: .NET MAUI Transparent Status Bar. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This worked for me. I have written platform specific code and then called them on the specific page's onappearing/ondisappearing methods.
Platform specific code + Dependency injection
MauiProgram.cs
public static class MauiProgram
{ 
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<StatusbarService>();
     }
}

StatusbarService.cs
namespace ExampleApp.Services.Partial; //Make sure the same namespace is used in the platform specific code.

public partial class StatusbarService
{
    public partial void ResetStatusBar();

    public partial void SetTranslucentStatusBar();
}

Home.xaml.cs
public partial class Home
{
    private readonly StatusbarService _statusbarService;

    public Home(HomeVM vm, StatusbarService statusbarService)
    {
        _statusbarService = statusbarService;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        _statusbarService.SetTranslucentStatusBar();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        _statusbarService.ResetStatusBar();
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
}

Platforms/Android
StatusbarService.cs
namespace ExampleApp.Services.Partial;
    
    public partial class StatusbarService
    {
        private static bool IsSupportedSDK => Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop;
    
        public partial void ResetStatusBar()
        {
            if (IsSupportedSDK)
            {
                Platform.CurrentActivity?.Window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
            }
        }
    
        public partial void SetTranslucentStatusBar()
        {
            if (IsSupportedSDK)
            {
                Platform.CurrentActivity?.Window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
            }
        }
    }

